# I could not connect to database instance created with Entity Framework generated from model

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I created a web application and a model. Then I generated a `dbcontext` class and a database instance. After I built the project, I tried to connect to that database from Server Explorer in Visual Studio, but could not connect.

I tried to test connection but got an error:

> This connection cannot be tested because the specified database does not exist or is not visible to the specified user

Whenever I tried to scaffold view or controller I got this error:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for ... one or more validation errors were detected during model generation
>   ModelsTable is based on type TestModel that has no keys defined.

When I created database object in controller class and write query got same error no key defined.

Also made updates on packages and tried again. I think my connection string is correct.

Here is my model.

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public bool IsWorking { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }
}
```

So I could not use scaffolding, Entity Framework and write query.

Here is my dbcontext class.

```
 public class ModelDB : DbContext
{

    public ModelDB()
        : base("name=ModelDB")
    {
    }


    public DbSet<TestModel> ModelsTable { get; set; }
}
```

I searched on internet tried founded solutions but did not understand and could not solve. I hope did not ask unnecessary questions. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Show `ModelsTable` and `TestModel` since that is what the error refers to.

Comment: I released wrote model name wrong and correct it. Also added ModelsTable.

Comment: What is your connection string? Start there if you are having connection errors.

Comment: Here is my connection string:                                                                             <add name="ModelDB" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=WebApplication3.Models.ModelDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Code First? If so I think you need to generate migrations.
In visual studio go to Package Manager Console and run this commands:

- Add-Migration "modelClassName"
- Update-Database –Verbose

For more information refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

You are missing the set; in the field ID.

Comment: Yes, I am using code first. I tried to enable migrations and got the same error: EntityType 'TestModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ModelsTable: EntityType: EntitySet 'ModelsTable' is based on type 'TestModel' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Have you tried to rename the field ID? I'd rename it to  TestModelID.

Comment: I tried as as TestModelID but result did not changed.

Comment: You are missing the set; in the field ID.

Comment: After writing set update database with migrations. Solved my all problems. Thanks for your helping. Should I delete question?

Comment: No you shouldn't it may help others.